# Azure devop .Net Core build can not find timespan

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, azure-devops, hsts

My project is .Net Core 3.1 and I'm using azure devop task called .Net Core to build my code.

I get this error:
##[error]projectNameSpace\Startup.cs(47,34): Error CS0103: The name 'TimeSpan' does not exist in the current context

```
        services.AddHsts(options =>
        {
            options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
        });
```

I also have "using System;" on top of the page.

Could someone help me understand this error a little better?

Comment: `using System;` should absolutely work.  Something else must be going on in your project to cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: I had to specify the System name space directly before timespan for it to be picked up.

```
        services.AddHsts(options =>
        {
            options.MaxAge = System.TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
        });
```

having "Using System;" on top of your class doesn't work.

Comment: Specifying the full namespace is always an *option*, but it should not be *required*.